# Conditional formatting of grid cells based on specifict attribute

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm using QGIS.

I have a 29x30km grid. Every cell of the grid has its ID and every cell of the grid has an attribute "Population" ranged from 0 to 30000.

What I would like to do, is to get some kind of heat map of the grid, eg. 30000 population cell is dark red, 100 population cell is light yellow.

The HeatMap plugin does not work (or I'm using it wrong), because AFAIK to get HeatMap from this plugin I'd have to convert my atrribute to eg. 30000 points in this cell.

Comment: What geometry type does your grid consist of?

Comment: It's "Polygon" (I've checked this using Metadata Properties of the layer with grid).

Comment: Select the layer, edit styles, classify by population and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a heatmap, you need a graduated or categorized symbol style. Just define the column as "Population", and play with the color ramp and mode to fit your required results.